# Как программно задать margin TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

Получаю данные и добавляю `TextView` в цикле, указать внутренний отступ могу, а вот с внешним отступом проблемка))

Вот код как я делаю:

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getInterests().getInterests().size(); i++) {
    com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout interestsLayout = (com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout) findViewById(R.id.interestsLayout);

    TextView interestsTextView = new TextView(UserPageActivity.this);
    interestsTextView.setText(userData.getInterests().getInterests().get(i).toString());
    interestsTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_button_gray);
    interestsTextView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textViewLayoutParams.setMargins(8,8,8,8);
    interestsTextView.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);

    interestsLayout.addView(interestsTextView); 
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: `textViewLayoutParams.setMargins(16,16,16,16);`

Comment: Спасибо большое)), не сработало, расстояние не меняется... что-то не то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос, простым добавлением пустого компонента с немного увеличенным размером, т.е. установил те отступы которые мне нужны)). Возможно это не правильно, но это работает и другого выхода я не нашел.

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getInterests().getInterests().size(); i++) {
    com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout interestsLayout = (com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout) findViewById(R.id.interestsLayout);

    TextView interestsTextView = new TextView(UserPageActivity.this);
    interestsTextView.setText(userData.getInterests().getInterests().get(i).toString());
    interestsTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_button_gray);
    interestsTextView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textViewLayoutParams.setMargins(8,8,8,8);
    interestsTextView.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);
    interestsLayout.addView(interestsTextView); 

    TextView nullTextView = new TextView(UserPageActivity.this);
    nullTextView.setText("");
    nullTextView.setPadding(5,10,5,20);
    nullTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
    interestsLayout.addView(nullTextView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Задавайте внешний отступ через ваш `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView interestsTextView = new TextView(UserPageActivity.this);

interestsTextView.setText(userData.getInterests().getInterests().get(i).toString());
interestsTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_button_gray);
interestsTextView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
params.setMargins(8,8,8,8);
interestsTextView.setLayoutParams(params);

interestsLayout.addView(interestsTextView);
```

Comment: В вопросе так и есть

Comment: Все что идёт в `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` поднимите выше `TextView`. То есть делайте это до объявления `TextView`

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) interestsTextView.getLayoutParams();` замените, и теперь точно должно сработать

Comment: Не совсем понял, на что нужно поменять?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: В таком случае, вообще ничего не отображается

Comment: @dev.android сделал правку, если и после этого не заработает, тогда не знаю

Comment: Так же как было (без отступов). Может быть причиной этого неприятного момента, что `LinearLayout` находится внутри `com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout interestsLayout = (com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout) findViewById(R.id.interestsLayout);`?

Comment: Вполне возможно